# Xamarin.Forms Android Entry Focus Breaks Layout on New Galaxy Phones ONLY

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, focus, textedit

For some inexplicable reason, focusing on certain entrys (textedits in native Android) within our app causes the parent container along with all of its contents to be pushed completely off the screen - and this problem only occurs on the Galaxy S8 and Galaxy Note 8.

The only difference between the entries that work correctly and those that do not seems to be the size of their parent containers. The larger the container, the more likely the problem is going to occur.

The following screenshots show the size difference - the entry in the first screenshot works as expected. The second screenshot is where the problem occurs.

[image: Screen 1]

[image: Screen 2]

Does anyone have any idea what is causing this or how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

This might be issue due to softinput mode in android you can try this **[Onscreenkeyboard issue in xamarin](https://xamarinhelp.com/accommodate-on-screen-keyboard-xamarin-forms/)**

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've tried both of the potential fixes mentioned in that article, but was unable to resolve the problem.